# Golang multipart uploads with chunked `http.GET` and Goamz `multi.PutAll`

Tags: go, goamz

I'm using the Goamz package and could use some help getting `bucket.Multi` to stream an HTTP GET response to S3.

I'll be downloading a 2+ GB file via chunked HTTP and I'd like to stream it directly into an S3 bucket.

It appears that I need to wrap the `resp.Body` with something so I can pass an implementation of `s3.ReaderAtSeeker` to `multi.PutAll`

```
// set up s3
auth, _ := aws.EnvAuth()
s3Con := s3.New(auth, aws.USEast)
bucket := s3Con.Bucket("bucket-name")

// make http request to URL
resp, err := http.Get(export_url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Get error %v\n", err)
    return
}

defer resp.Body.Close()

// set up multi-part 
multi, err := bucket.InitMulti(s3Path, "text/plain", s3.Private, s3.Options{})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("InitMulti error %v\n", err)
    return
}

// Need struct that implements: s3.ReaderAtSeeker
// type ReaderAtSeeker interface {
//  io.ReaderAt
//  io.ReadSeeker
// }

rs := // Question: what can i wrap `resp.Body` in?

parts, err := multi.PutAll(rs, 5120)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("PutAll error %v\n", err)
    return
}

err = multi.Complete(parts)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Complete error %v\n", err)
    return
}
```

Currently I get the following (expected) error when trying to run my program:

```
./main.go:50: cannot use resp.Body (type io.ReadCloser) as type s3.ReaderAtSeeker in argument to multi.PutAll:
    io.ReadCloser does not implement s3.ReaderAtSeeker (missing ReadAt method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You haven't indicated which package you're using to access the S3 api but I'm assuming it's this one</del> https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/.

Since your file is of a significant in size, a possible solution might be to use the [multi.PutPart](https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/blob/master/s3/multi.go#L144). This will give you more control than [multi.PutAll](https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/blob/master/s3/multi.go#L278). Using the [Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader) from the standard library, your approach would be:

1. Get the Content-Length from the response header
2. Get the number of parts needed based on Content-Length and partSize
3. Loop over number of part and read []byte from response.Body into bytes.Reader and call multi.PutPart
4. Get parts from [multi.ListParts](https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/blob/master/s3/multi.go#L235)
5. call multi.Complete with parts.

I don't have access to S3 so I can't test my hypothesis but the above could be worth exploring if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to use - http://github.com/minio/minio-go

It implements PutObject() which is a fully managed self contained operation for uploading large files. It also automatically does multipart for more than 5MB worth of data in parallel.  if no pre-defined ContentLength is specified. It will keep uploading until it reaches EOF.

Following example shows how to do it, when one doesn't have a pre-defined input length but an io.Reader which is streaming. In this example i have used "os.Stdin" as an equivalent for your chunked input.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/minio/minio-go"
)

func main() {
    config := minio.Config{
        AccessKeyID:     "YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE",
        SecretAccessKey: "YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE",
        Endpoint:        "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
    }
    s3Client, err := minio.New(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    err = s3Client.PutObject("mybucket", "myobject", "application/octet-stream", 0, os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

}
$ echo "Hello my new-object" | go run stream-object.go
```